# How to use AND, OR operators in isset query in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can I use && or like this in a query, is this the correct syntax?

```
if($_SESSION['session_user_type'] == 'user' && $del_date1 == '' or $del_date1 > $row_cap['cap_date']){}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `or` operator in PHP I use is `||`.

Try something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['session_user_type'] == 'user' && ($del_date1 == '' || $del_date1 > $row_cap['cap_date'])) ...
```

Notice how the `||` bit is inside brackets. I'm assuming you want it separate from the `and` - since you are checking `$del_date1` to be one of two values.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what are you trying to achieve, `&&` have a higher precedence than `||`, and `||` is higher than `OR`.
To avoid this **Precedence problem**, use parantheses.

Here is the [PHP Operator Precedence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) table for more details.